# Hyperlink multi-level sub-directories through index.php? structure

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a hyperlink structure that can access multi-level sub folders. For now, I can access my hyperlinks with only one-level (php) directory, such like `index.php?content=about` (whereas 'about' is about.php).

What I want to do is to create a filing system for a larger website with multi-level sub-directories like the following example,
`index.php?blog/category/process/`.  I don't know if there is a symbol that replaces html symbol / (slash for directory) but for PHP directories. I tried different ways of accessing files inside multi-level sub-directories, such as putting the ? (question mark).  It was all hypothetically experimental.  If I use the slash, such in the form '`blog/category/process/filename.php`', I get a **404 Not Found** error.

There is the following PHP script inside function.php, that gets the content from the URL, if there is no content, it sets a default and if there is content, it sanitizes data against hacking:

```
function loadContent($where, $default='') {
$content = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $where, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$default = filter_var($default, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$content = (empty($content)) ? $default : $content;

if ($content) {
$html = include 'content/'.$content.'.php';
return $html;
  }
}

function loadIncludes($where, $default='includes/') {

$includes = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $where, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$default = filter_var($default, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($includes) {

$html = include 'includes/'.$includes.'.php';
    return $html;
  }
}
```

The link to the document inside 'blog/category/process/filename.php' shows up (where it was '404 Error' before, but the header and the css files do not work. They are not been picked up.

*Please note:*
My website structure is
Header  (one header picked up by index.php?)
Content  (multiple content=filename.php)
Footer

index.php looks like this:

```
<?php   
require ('includes/function.php');
require ('includes/init.php');  /* init.php picks up the header */
?>

<div class="clearboth"></div>

<!-- ********  HOMEPAGE  **********  -->
<?php loadContent('content', 'home'); ?>

<div class="clearboth"></div>

<!-- ********  FOOTER  **********  -->  
<?php include ('content/footer.php');  ?>
```

---

I found the solution on the structure of the multi-level sub-directories through index.php? that also picks up the CSS, which is as follows:

```
<a href="index.php?content=blog/category/process/filename">
(leave out the extension .php followed after 'filename')
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: What server-side technology do you use ? Apache ?

Comment: 1. Can you edit .htaccess rules ? What is your actual Rewrite rules in the .htaccess.

Comment: @eLearner  <code>#RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
</code>  ---  I do not mind sharing my website address here, but I am not sure if it would be against the rules.  Thank you for looking into my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/* FOLDERS STRUCTURE

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = C:/Server/www/music; // YES Windows :)
THIS FILE = folders.php

C:/Server/www/music
C:/Server/www/music/files/
C:/Server/www/music/files/folder1/
C:/Server/www/music/files/folder1/folder2/myfile.jpeg

*/

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$startFolder = '/files/';
preg_match('/\?/', $requestURI) ? list($requestURI, $fileToFind) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : exit('Bad request'); 
$file = $root.$startFolder.$fileToFind;    

if(file_exists($file)){

    //YOUR CODE 
}
else {

    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

}

// Usage = http://music.com/folders.php?/folder1/folder2/myfile.jpeg
?>
```

Read those questions I had asked before. I hope it will help you

> [.htaccess : Redirect all http requests to one file whitout 404 resp. code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655618/htaccess-redirect-all-http-requests-to-one-file-whitout-404-resp-code)
>
> [Use PHP to rewrite URLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646561/use-php-to-rewrite-urls)

Note that you may play with http headers `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");` or `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 Ok");` In case the file exists or not

Active your imagination...

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I copy/pasted your script as a .php file and did a 'require_once'. Result, my homepage disappeared. Navigation menu in header is visible on index.php file.  Links work but the multi-level directory structure is still not working. I suspect, that I may have mis-represented my question. What I need is  // Usage = http://music.com/index.php?folder1/folder2/myfile.PHP. Currently, it is only a one-level navigation system. Multi-level directory structure only works inside CSS file, e.g. ../img/thumbnails/mypicture.jpg.  Not as navigation inside PHP files.

Comment: Thank you for compiling the above script, I appreciate your time and knowledge.  I have modified my original question above.  It may help in the next step.

Comment: Sorry ! (Holidays) Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Not yet.  Appreciate you following up.    :)

Comment: @ e-Learner, thank you so much for your continued help.  Your directions towards 'Use PHP to rewrite URLS' was a great lead!  I investigated from there and found my answer I was looking for, for quite some time now.  I hope this also helps others who I googled with similar problem, but they had kept strictly the one-level sub-directory structure.  Someone advised to use 'explode' but the above solution, I find, is so much simpler.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the hyperlink structure of a multi-level sub-directories through index.php? that also picks up the CSS, and does not issue a 404 Error, which is as follows:

```
<a href="index.php?content=blog/category/process/filename">
descriptive header
</a>
```

(note:  remember to leave out the extension .php followed after 'filename')

Comment: Of course. What do you think `'content/'.$content.'.php'` will produce, if `$content` is "*blog/category/process/filename.php*"? Yes, it will be obviously "*content/blog/category/process/filename.php.php*". If you're not doing even elementary debugging, you won't be able to code anything. It would be enough to just print a content of the variable `$html` and you would see that.

Comment: @ Dawid,  I think there is a misunderstanding.  My question was not on adding .php or leaving it out.  I was trying to access the file in a multi-level sub-folder.   I never had a problem with adding the extension .php in to end of the filename.  The note is for those only as a reminder to leave the .php extension out.  Look at my answer again, it says   ...content=blog/category/process/filename...  it was the = (equal sign) that was crucial here and still keep the forward slashes for the rest of the folders.

Comment: I see. But you knew from the start, what's the right URL: `index.php?content=about`. There is nothing special about how you say "multi-level sub-folder". The URL is still the same: `index.php?content=how/many/sub/levels/you/want`. Anyway I'm glad you have solved it yourself.

Comment: @ Dawid,  I didn't know how to resolve it.  It is a book learned strategy and no example was shown for multi-level, as the content is a folder itself, guessing that the rest would be slash was a wild guess.  I went from =$1& and many other character guesses.  Just did not make sense to me why the equal and then followed by slashes.  But thank thank you...  :)

Comment: That's simple. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). Part of URL after the question mark is called *query*. It's in format `parameter1=value&parameter2=value...`. Your parameter is `content` (as used in PHP script) and its value can be whatever. You need to set it to path. In Linux path is delimited by a slash (as opposed by back-slash on Windows). Therefore you need `content=path/to/file`. Whole `index.php?content=whatever` for webserver means: execute `index.php` and set `content` parameter to "whatever". PHP script includes what's in `content` param.

Comment: @ Dawid, thanks for the explanation on its workings.